# XML Schema: Errors when using more than one namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

I am learning XML at uni and am having difficulty with using more than one namespace. As you can see from the following code, I wanted the element "enquiries" to have its own namespace. Following some online research, I gathered that in order to support that in the XML Schema, I would need to create a type for it in a separate xsd file, and then import this xsd to the main xsd file.

I tried to do that and I thought I did it well, but when I validate the XML I am getting a lot of errors.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

invoice.xml:

```
<invoice xmlns="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/invoices"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/invoices invoice.xsd">
    <company>b2b Software Magic Ltd</company>
    <reference>MyNet201</reference>
    <date>2005-11-11</date>
    <enquiries xmlns:enq="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/enquiriesType">
        <enq:name>Paul White</enq:name>
        <enq:phone>0207 634 6547</enq:phone>
    </enquiries>
    <clientbusiness>
        <id>345533</id>
        <contactname>Mr Barrny Hales</contactname>
        <name>MyNetGlobix Plc</name>
        <address>
            <street>2 Caxton Street</street>
            <city>London</city>
            <postcode>SW1 H0QE</postcode>
        </address>
    </clientbusiness>
    <products>
        <product>
            <description>Golden number development version 2 (1 day)</description>
            <amount currency="GBP">500.00</amount>
        </product>
    </products>
    <finalamounts>
        <NET currency="GBP">500.00</NET>
        <VAT>
            <percent>17.5</percent>
            <amount currency="GBP">87.50</amount>
        </VAT>
        <total currency="GBP">587.50</total>
    </finalamounts>
</invoice>
```

invoice.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/invoices"
        xmlns="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/invoices"
        xmlns:enq="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/enquiriesType"
        >
    <xs:import schemaLocation="enquiriesType.xsd" namespace="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/enquiriesType" />

    <xs:element name="amount">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:float" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="invoice">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence> <!-- Maybe change to "all"? -->
                <xs:element name="company" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="reference" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date" />
                <xs:element name="enquiries" type="enq:enquiriesType" />

                <xs:element name="clientbusiness">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
                            <xs:element name="contactname" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="address">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element name="postcode" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="products">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="product">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:element ref="amount" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="finalamounts">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="NET">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:float" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="VAT">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="percent" type="xs:float" />
                                        <xs:element ref="amount" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="total">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:float" />
                                        </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

enquiriesType.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://www.fakenamespace.com/ns/enquiriesType"
        >
    <xs:complexType name="enquiriesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="enq:string" />
            <xs:element name="phone" type="enq:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and fixed all the problems:

- I used the wrong namespace in xmlns:enq in the file invoice.xsd (I've already corrected it by editing my original post).
- I used type="enq:string" instead of type="xs:string" in the file enquiriesType.xsd.

I also had another recurring mistake: I used type="xs:float" instead of type="xs:string" for the "currency" attribute.